# Check the given value is a letter or number; if number then check whether it's even or odd

Tags: python

```
ch = input("Enter any value: ")
if((ch>='a' and ch<='z') or (ch>='A' and ch<='Z')):
    print(ch, "is an alphabet.")
elif(ch%2==0):
    print("even")
else(ch%2=!0):
    print("odd")
```

Comment: What is your question? You've provided a task and some code, but we don't know what question you are trying to ask or what error you are facing.

Comment: you're forgetting to convert to integer if not a letter. But in that case, test for exception… or test chars 02468 13579 it'll be simpler

Comment: Just because a character isn't a letter doesn't mean it is numeric, and it certainly doesn't mean you can treat it as a number.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check if a value is a number is to, well, try it.

```
ch = input("Enter any value: ")
try:
    v = int(ch)
except ValueError:
    print(ch, "is not a number")
else:
    if v % 2 == 0:
        print("even")
    else:
        print("odd")
```

Comment: I wouldn't bother here. If it returns `True`, you're just going to call `int(ch)` anyway.